# Sonar build error on Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

My Jenkins build is failing with this below error.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:50.002s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 15 03:59:51 CST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 76M/405M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project com.fico.om.dam.assembly: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch$Builder.setBootstrapProperties(Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/sonar/batch/bootstrapper/Batch$Builder;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.0.1/sonar-maven-plugin-3.0.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/root/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/sonar-runner/sonar-runner-api/2.5.1/sonar-runner-api-2.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/root/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I tried clearing the ".m2", even this didn't work. Could you please help.
Java jdk: 1.7.0_15 , Maven: 3.0.5.
Do let me know if you need more details.

snippet of pom.xml
`

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <checkstyle.config.location>../../../COMMON/Source/com.masked/om_checks.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
    <checkstyle.outputFile>target/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</checkstyle.outputFile>
    <findbug.XMLOutputDirectory>target/findbugs</findbug.XMLOutputDirectory>
    <!-- Sonar -->
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../com.masked/target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <buildNumber>SNAPSHOT</buildNumber>
    <dotExecutable>C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/dot.exe</dotExecutable>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
                <xmlOutputDirectory>${findbug.XMLOutputDirectory}</xmlOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        jacoco-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [0.6.3.201306030806,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.5.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-resources-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.6,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-dependency-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <configuration>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>aggregate</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <configLocation>${checkstyle.configLocation}</configLocation>
                <outputFile>${checkstyle.outputFile}</outputFile>
                <excludes>${checkstyle.excludes}</excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>XYZRelease</id>
        <name>FDO Release</name>
        <url>http://pkrappcmf400:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>xqj</id>
        <name>XQJ Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://xqj.net/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>basex</id>
        <name>BaseX Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://files.basex.org/maven</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>XYZRelease</id>
        <name>FDO Release</name>
        <url>http://pkrappcmf400:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

`

Comment: Which version of the SonarQube server you use?

Answer (score 0):

First you should try to update your Maven version in case there is a bug with relocation support. Then you should check your Maven configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your Question**

1. When you error with like this

   > strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy

your Maven Repository (Nexus)is not constructed properly (i.e) not having appropriate dependencies JAR files.

2. Plexus compiler dependencies will require these below list of JAR's (which is mentioned in Log Files) as a dependencies, if you miss any single JAR you will get this kind of Exception. And this has nothing to do with your Maven Version.
3. Please refer my Log files (Replaced with your Repository) and Ensure these **Plexus related JAR files** gets downloaded in your Local Maven Repository.

   ```
                   <checkstyle.config.location>../../../COMMON/Source/com.masked/om_checks.xml</checkstyle.config.location>
                   <checkstyle.outputFile>target/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</checkstyle.outputFile>
                   <findbug.XMLOutputDirectory>target/findbugs</findbug.XMLOutputDirectory>
                   [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
               [INFO] Scanning for projects...
               [INFO] Building sonarapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.5.201505241946/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.5.201505241946/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.5.201505241946.pom (4 KB at 1.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.build-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.build/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.build-0.7.5.201505241946.pom (36 KB at 148.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.5.201505241946/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin/0.7.5.201505241946/jacoco-maven-plugin-0.7.5.201505241946.jar (50 KB at 249.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Deleting C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\target
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:prepare-agent (prepare-agent) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.pom (2 KB at 9.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.pom (4 KB at 25.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.pom (4 KB at 33.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.2/maven-artifact-2.0.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.2/maven-artifact-2.0.2.pom (765 B at 5.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.2/maven-2.0.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.2/maven-2.0.2.pom (13 KB at 75.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.pom (767 B at 5.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.2/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.2/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.2.pom (2 KB at 9.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.2/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.2/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.2.pom (2 KB at 10.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.pom (588 B at 3.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-1.0-alpha-6.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-1.0-alpha-6.pom (7 KB at 44.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.pom (5 KB at 23.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0/doxia-sink-api-1.0.pom (2 KB at 7.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0/doxia-1.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.0/doxia-1.0.pom (10 KB at 40.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/10/maven-parent-10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/10/maven-parent-10.pom (31 KB at 162.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.10/maven-project-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-project/2.0.10/maven-project-2.0.10.pom (3 KB at 17.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.10/maven-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/2.0.10/maven-2.0.10.pom (24 KB at 124.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.10/maven-settings-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.0.10/maven-settings-2.0.10.pom (3 KB at 16.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.10/maven-model-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-model/2.0.10/maven-model-2.0.10.pom (4 KB at 23.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.pom (2 KB at 10.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.10/maven-profile-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-profile/2.0.10/maven-profile-2.0.10.pom (3 KB at 12.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.10/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact-manager/2.0.10/maven-artifact-manager-2.0.10.pom (3 KB at 15.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.10/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0.10/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.10.pom (3 KB at 13.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.10/maven-artifact-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-artifact/2.0.10/maven-artifact-2.0.10.pom (2 KB at 10.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.10/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-registry/2.0.10/maven-plugin-registry-2.0.10.pom (2 KB at 14.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.10/maven-plugin-api-2.0.10.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0.10/maven-plugin-api-2.0.10.pom (2 KB at 9.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1.2/doxia-sink-api-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.1.2/doxia-sink-api-1.1.2.pom (2 KB at 8.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.1.2/doxia-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia/1.1.2/doxia-1.1.2.pom (18 KB at 111.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1.2/doxia-logging-api-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-logging-api/1.1.2/doxia-logging-api-1.1.2.pom (2 KB at 11.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.pom (4 KB at 25.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.12/plexus-utils-1.5.12.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.12/plexus-utils-1.5.12.pom (6 KB at 39.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.pom (3 KB at 13.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.03/xml-apis-1.3.03.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.03/xml-apis-1.3.03.pom (738 B at 5.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/apache/1/apache-1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/apache/1/apache-1.pom (4 KB at 25.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.pom (8 KB at 84.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.pom (6 KB at 51.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.pom (4 KB at 26.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.2/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.2/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.2.pom (6 KB at 26.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sitetools/1.1.2/doxia-sitetools-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sitetools/1.1.2/doxia-sitetools-1.1.2.pom (15 KB at 93.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.2/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.2/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.2.pom (3 KB at 19.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.2.pom (2 KB at 9.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-modules/1.1.2/doxia-modules-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-modules/1.1.2/doxia-modules-1.1.2.pom (3 KB at 14.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.2/doxia-module-fml-1.1.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.2/doxia-module-fml-1.1.2.pom (6 KB at 38.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.pom (2 KB at 7.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.12/plexus-components-1.1.12.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-components/1.1.12/plexus-components-1.1.12.pom (3 KB at 15.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.pom (2 KB at 10.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-20.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-20.pom (3 KB at 17.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-20.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-containers/1.0-alpha-20/plexus-containers-1.0-alpha-20.pom (2 KB at 14.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexus-utils-1.3.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexus-utils-1.3.pom (2 KB at 5.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-7/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-7.pom (3 KB at 14.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.9/plexus-1.0.9.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus/1.0.9/plexus-1.0.9.pom (8 KB at 44.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.pom (8 KB at 54.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.pom (11 KB at 98.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.pom (9 KB at 46.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom (357 B at 2.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.pom (866 B at 9.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.pom (974 B at 5.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom (3 KB at 15.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.pom (163 B at 1.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.0/commons-collections-2.0.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.0/commons-collections-2.0.pom (171 B at 1.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.pom (4 KB at 27.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom (346 B at 1.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946.pom (3 KB at 14.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.pom (2 KB at 6.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.pom (2 KB at 11.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.1/asm-parent-5.0.1.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/5.0.1/asm-parent-5.0.1.pom (6 KB at 28.2 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.pom
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.pom (2 KB at 6.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-alpha-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar (42 KB at 181.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar (37 KB at 126.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.1.jar (17 KB at 54.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar (39 KB at 116.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.jar (232 KB at 551.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.2/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar (30 KB at 63.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.2/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.1.2/doxia-core-1.1.2.jar (155 KB at 312.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.1.2/doxia-module-xhtml-1.1.2.jar (15 KB at 23.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.2/doxia-module-fml-1.1.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.1.2/doxia-decoration-model-1.1.2.jar (52 KB at 76.9 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar (11 KB at 12.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.1.2/doxia-module-fml-1.1.2.jar (37 KB at 43.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.1.2/doxia-site-renderer-1.1.2.jar (50 KB at 52.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar (298 KB at 282.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar (383 KB at 325.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar (1185 KB at 964.6 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar (89 KB at 71.4 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar (558 KB at 429.1 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar (8 KB at 5.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar (185 KB at 134.5 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar (38 KB at 26.3 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloading: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.jar
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar (165 KB at 115.8 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.core/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.core-0.7.5.201505241946.jar (131 KB at 88.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar (282 KB at 176.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.1/asm-debug-all-5.0.1.jar (372 KB at 230.7 KB/sec)
               [INFO] Downloaded: http://pkrappcmf400:8081/maven2/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.report/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.report-0.7.5.201505241946.jar (137 KB at 85.0 KB/sec)
               [INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:D:\\maven_repo\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.7.5.201505241946\\org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\Users\\YourID\\workspace\\sonarapp\\target\\jacoco.exec,append=true
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ sonarapp ---
               [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
               [INFO] Copying 0 resource
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Not copying test resources
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Not compiling test sources
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Tests are skipped.
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.5.201505241946:report (report) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file:C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\target\jacoco.exec
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Packaging webapp
               [INFO] Assembling webapp [sonarapp] in [C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\target\sonarapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
               [INFO] Processing war project
               [INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\src\main\webapp]
               [INFO] Webapp assembled in [110 msecs]
               [INFO] Building war: C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\target\sonarapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
               [INFO] 
               [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ sonarapp ---
               [INFO] Installing C:\Users\HOME\workspace\sonarapp\target\sonarapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to D:\maven_repo\com\basic\app\sonarapp\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\sonarapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
               [INFO] Installing C:\Users\YourID\workspace\sonarapp\pom.xml to D:\maven_repo\com\basic\app\sonarapp\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\sonarapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
               [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
               [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
               [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
               [INFO] Total time: 32.463 s
               [INFO] Finished at: 2016-02-15T18:33:57+05:30
               [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M
               [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```